# Combine voltage sources

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, voltage-source, low-voltage, undervoltage

I have a Baldor DG6E generator.  It must produce 120V/240V but I bought it and it has three wires as outlets - every one produces 120V.  I want to combine two wires to produce 240V. How can I combine two wires to produce 240V or is there is another way to make the generator produce 120V/240V?

Comment: Short version of the answer: you can't. 

You can, however, get a step up transformer to go from 120 to 240.

Answer (score 1):

If the generator does not have a 240 VAC output then it's unlikely you can combine two 120 VAC outputs to get 240 VAC.  The only way I can think of that is both safe and reasonably inexpensive (for some definitions of "reasonably") is a transformer.

How much power do you need from this 240 VAC output?  If it's less than 1000 watts, or perhaps 2000 watts, then you could possibly pick up a step up transformer from a hardware store for under $100.  Any bigger than that and it's probably cheaper to buy a new generator with a proper 240 VAC output.

An example of such a transformer here:  https://www.homedepot.com/p/Power-Bright-2000-Watts-Step-Up-Down-Converter-110-120-Volt-220-240-Volt-Voltage-Transformer-VC2000W/302542246

Comment: Looking again at the question, and in searching on the model number given for the generator, I'm convinced that you have not read the manual.  Read the manual and it will tell you how to get 240 VAC output.  Read the manual.  If you are still confused then contact the manufacturer or where you bought the generator.

Answer (score 0):

The three wires are for Neutral, and two 120VAC lines which are 180 \$ ^\circ \$ out of phase.

The DG6E has a 120/240 VAC output using a NEMA L14-30R connector according to the manual.

You can get 240 VAC between the two 120VAC lines(marked Gold).

Check out the manual : https://www.baldor.com/Shared/manuals/2414-104.pdf
How to use the connector : http://www.generatorsforhomeuse.us/l14-30/

As always, take extreme precaution when working with these and check the warnings.